# How to use app which is EXPO in react native?

Tags: react-native

*I start to use expo it seems so useful however there is no android file in expo project file or IOS file ? I couldnt find how to add android or ios file. Anyone has idea ?*

Answer (score 2):

You have to use react native CLI for changing iOS or Android code separately .

" If you are coming from a web background, the easiest way to get started with React Native is with Expo tools because they allow you to start a project without installing and configuring Xcode or Android Studio. Expo CLI sets up a development environment on your local machine and you can be writing a React Native app within minutes "

You can find more information in this link : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#the-react-native-cli-1

Comment: Oh, do u suggest to use expo ?

Comment: No, i suggest to put effort and learn the react native cli . it'll do all the things expo do and you can customize your app as much as need with it

Answer (score 1):

Expo projects don't have Android or iOS folders. They're hidden and Expo takes care of them for you.

To run your app, run `expo start` in your project directory. This will start the Expo Dev Server, from where you can run and debug your app on emulator/device.

Hope that is clear enough.

Comment: Yes i can run my project  however,  forexample when I need to give permission or need to change version of app how can I do them ?

Comment: @hakan You can specify permissions or version inside app.json instead.

Comment: Check out the expo docs for details: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/